# How do I get gcc to use an alternate version of a library?

Tags: gcc, linker

I am trying to compile a package that requires zlib v1.2.8. The system - to which I do not have root access - has zlib 1.2.3 in /lib64. I built the newer version of zlib and changed the makefile like so:

```
CFLAGS=-I/mydir/zlib/include
LDFLAGS=-L/mydir/zlib/lib -lz -lm -lpthread -lbz2
```

This compiles and links successfully, but at run time I get

```
/lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.3.3' not found (required by ./myapp)
```

How can I get the linker to ignore the older version of zlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either statically link it by using:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/mydir/zlib/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lz -Wl,-Bdynamic -lm -lpthread -lbz2
```

or you can use [runpaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath):

```
LDFLAGS=-L/mydir/zlib/lib -Wl,-rpath,/mydir/zlib/lib -lz -lm -lpthread -lbz2
```

`-Wl` flags are used to tell gcc "pass this flag directly to the linker and don't check it at all".

the linker flags are documented in the [GNU binutils ld manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html).

tl;dr:

- `-Bstatic`: use static linking after this point in the command line
- `-Bdynamic`: use dynamic linking after this point in the command line
- `-rpath`: save this path in the program and tell the [ld.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) to search it first for libraries at runtime

Comment: Could you explain the -W and -B flags?

Comment: i've added more details/links for each part.  hth.